# How to UPDATE with LATERAL Nearest-Neighbour query?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, proximity, knn

Say I have table `gps` like:

```
CREATE TABLE gps(
   gps_id serial primary key,
   measured_timestamp timestamp, 
   geom Geometry(Point,4326),
   stop_id int --Null
);
```

And I have a table of stops like:

```
CREATE TABLE stops(
   stop_id serial primary key,
   geom Geometry(Point,4326)
);
```

If I want to do an `UPDATE` on `gps` to find the nearest stop to each point, is there a way to use a `LATERAL` query?

I tried something like

```
UPDATE gps
SET stop_id = nearest.stop_id
FROM LATERAL(SELECT stop_id FROM stops ORDER BY stops.geom <-> gps.geom LIMIT 1) nearest
```

but that told me

```
ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "gps"
                                               ^
HINT:  There is an entry for table "gps", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
```

So is the only way to do?

```
UPDATE gps
SET stop_id = nearest.stop_id
FROM (SELECT gps.gps_id, stop_id 
      FROM gps
      LATERAL JOIN (SELECT stop_id FROM stops ORDER BY stops.geom <-> gps.geom LIMIT 1) stops) nearest
WHERE nearest.gps_id = gps.gps_id
```

This feels like joining the same table to itself, which wouldn't need to happen with a `SELECT INTO`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No need for `JOIN LATERAL` (or do you *really* just want to use it?); an `UPDATE` will pass each processing row to the following query, which is the same concept as using a `JOIN LATERAL`.[*]
Try

```
UPDATE gps
  SET  stop_id = (
    SELECT stops.stop_id
    FROM   stops
    ORDER BY
           gps.geom <-> stops.geom
    LIMIT  1
  )
;
```

---

[*] Just to give an example on that; consider a `SELECT` instead to find the closest `stop` to each `gps` point using `JOIN LATERAL`:

```
SELECT a.gps_id,
       a.measured_timestamp,
       a.geom,
       b.stop_id
FROM   gps AS a
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT stops.stop_id
  FROM   stops
  ORDER BY
         a.geom <-> stops.geom
  LIMIT  1
) AS b
;
```

Each row in `gps` is now passed individually and subsequentially to the `JOIN LATERAL` sub-query to be processed; this (sort of) mimicks the `UPDATE` command (note how it is the same sub-query).

Comment: Ah the solution was much simpler than I thought. We _were_ initially doing a `SELECT * INTO` using `LATERAL` but wanted to know which rows fail the KNN + conditions, while also not needlessly duplicating data.

Comment: Follow up question: if I wanted to SET multiple columns this way would I move the subquery to `FROM` or would I repeat the subquery for each column?

Comment: @raphael damn, accidentally deleted my comment, so again: move to `FROM` (...you got me there, I'm not 100% sure, but I guess that you can assign multiple `SET` columns if the subquery returns only one distinct value per column, as with the *stop_id* in the example, without a `WHERE` condition)

Comment: I'll play around with it and report back.

Comment: @raphael got it: `... SET (<col1>, <col2>) = (<query>)` where `<query>` (as above) returns two columns in respective order, having one distinct value each..

Comment: wow, that's a great tip. `UPDATE foo SET (col1, col2) = (SELECT col1, col2 FROM bar WHERE ST_DWithin([...]) ORDER BY [...] <-> [...] LIMIT 1)`

Comment: @ThingumaBob this did work for me, but trying to process a few hundred thousand records at a time threw errors about: "ERROR: could not write block 313673 of temporary file: No space left on device" - so I ended up processing about 100k at a time and it seems to work.

Comment: @DPSSpatial I think that´s in fact a common practice for large tables since an `UPDATE` is resource heavy most of the time. The `JOIN LATERAL` will add up to this, maybe using a CTE can be helpful? I´m no expert here, but maybe it´s worth checking your `work_mem` value to minimize temporary disk storage etc. Also, on large tables, it´s at least faster, maybe even less demanding, to create a new table instead (I read that a long while ago, can´t find source)

Answer (score 0):

And if you want to store this minimal distance in your gps table you can use this code:

```
ALTER TABLE gps
ADD min_distance float8;

UPDATE gps
SET min_distance = list.distance
FROM(
    SELECT gps.gps_id AS name, MIN(gps.geom <-> stops.geom) AS distance
    FROM gps
    CROSS JOIN stops
    GROUP BY gps.gps_id
    ORDER BY gps.gps_id)
    AS list
WHERE gps.gps_id = list.name;
```