# Optmizing PostGIS minimum distance query

Tags: postgis, distance, spatial-query, optimization, knn

I have the `field_1` of my `Table_1` that must have the minimum distance between the geometry of my `Table_1` and any geometry of my `Table_2`.
To do so, I used a `CROSS JOIN` (Full Cartesian Product) between `Table_1` and `Table_2`. I also used the KNN operator `<->`.

My trouble is that it took more than 3 hours to run and I decided to abort the query while it was running.

`Table_1` has `56230` entities.

`Table_2` has `234843` entities.

Here is my code:

```
UPDATE Table_1
SET field_1 = list.distance
FROM(
    SELECT T1.gid AS name, MIN(T1.geom <-> T2.geom) AS distance
    FROM Table_1 AS T1
    CROSS JOIN Table_2 AS T2
    GROUP BY T1.gid
    ORDER BY T1.gid
     ) AS list
WHERE Table_1.gid = list.name;
```

Do you have any ideas with a lighter query that could execute this much faster ? I already have created spatial indices.

Comment: see e.g. [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/278362/93656) for the *(K)NN* `UPDATE` syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the [`<->`](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_distance_knn.html) operator will use the index only if it is within the `order by` clause.

You can rewrite your query

```sql
select a.id,closest_pt.id, closest_pt.dist
from tablea a
CROSS JOIN LATERAL
  (SELECT
     id , 
     a.geom <-> b.geom as dist
     FROM tableb b
     ORDER BY a.geom <-> b.geom
   LIMIT 1) AS closest_pt;
```

Comment: Your query is very efficient. But when I change it to update my field_1, the time taken is very long. It seems that updating is not as efficient as selecting. Any idea to lower the computing time ?

Comment: Looks like it is repeating the first query the number of entities in the table_1. Can't it be done for once ?