# Query to Map GPS points with multi-linestring

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I have a column of geometry of type multi-linestring in a database as in the following format

[image]

Now I want to add a new column of speed by mapping GPS points against geometry column (as described below that has been listed on separate CSV file).
[image]

Tell me how I query to merge the speed column (captured against GPS coordinate points) with existing geometries

Answer (score 1):

First, you can identify for each point the nearest line by using the postgis ST_Distance function (geometry_point,geometry_line) and a LIMIT 1 to keep only the nearest line.

In a second step, thanks to an attribute join, you will be able to add speed to your lines.

If you need help in executing these requests, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: even better: don't use `ST_Distance`, use the '*KNN*' operator `<->`: check [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/278362/93656) answer for an optimized nearest-neighbor search in an `UPDATE` statement (@HuniyaSohail change accordingly to select the `speed` column of your points).